# Primefaces tree как с ним работать?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, дерево

Код класса:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

@ManagedBean(name="treeBasicView")
@ViewScoped
public class BasicView implements Serializable {

private TreeNode root;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
    TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);
    TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);

    TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);
    TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);

    TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);

    node1.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1"));
    node00.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0"));
    node00.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1"));
    node01.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0"));
    node10.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0"));
    root.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2"));
}

public TreeNode getRoot() {
    return root;
}
}
```

Код странички:

```
<h:form>
<h3 style="margin-top:0">Client</h3>
<p:tree value="#{treeBasicView.root}" var="node">
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>

<h3>Ajax</h3>
<p:tree value="#{treeBasicView.root}" var="node" dynamic="true">
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
</h:form>
```

При запуске выдает просто три точки:

.

.

.

Я не могу понять почему. А ещё большая загадка, это : value="#{node}" Что такое node? Откуда он тянет значения?

Comment: Х.з. что за точки. Может какие-то ошибки помимо дерева. А #{node} - это текущий узел, вернее данные, положенные в узел дерева. Берётся из var="node". Так задаётся переменная итератора, на которую можно ссылаться в компонентах, которые должны как-то изобразить эти узлы.

Comment: Ваш код полностью работоспобен - скопировал и запустил у себя, всё ОК, вижу два древа, есть названия, узлы корректно разворачиваются. Из приведённого кода не ясно, что у вас есть снаружи формы, возможно проблема там. Попробуйте максимально "урезать" содержимое странички, оставив на странице только <h:head/>, <h:body> и <f:view>.